# wpf making the same button show different info after multiple clicks

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating something that has buttons, to show different info. I don't want to create a lot of buttons, but I don't know how to have the buttons show different information.

```
<Button x:Name="btn1"
        Content=""
        Click="btn1_Click"/>
<Button x:Name="btn2"
        Content=""
        Click="btn2_Click"/>
<Button x:Name="btn3"
        Content=""
        Click="btn3_Click"/>
<Button x:Name="btn4"
        Content=""
        Click="btn4_Click"/>
<Button x:Name="btn5"
        Content=""
        Visibility="Hidden"
        Click="btn5_Click"/>
<Button x:Name="btn6"
        Content=""
        Visibility="Hidden"
        Click="btn6_Click"/>
<Button x:Name="btnBack"
        Content="Return to Main Menu"
        Visibility="Hidden"
        Click="btnBack_Click"/>
```

if you click `btn1` from the main menu and click it again it will show info, but after clicking `btn2` from the main menu and clicking `btn1`, it will show different info. I don't know how I could do that, and nothing i searched up has helped me so far.

Comment: Did you write button_click event on c# for your buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Anything with a bunch of generic controls created by hand has a smell to it in WPF and your's is no different. This may sound bad, but in reality is something extremely good when it comes to WPF. Why? Because this means you get to learn how dynamic WPF is and you get to hopefully learn how to overcome the smell (at least for this situation).

***Disclaimer:*** The pieces and ideas are here, but making a full working solution is not needed and may actually hinder the learning process.

You obviously have some dynamic buttons and you want to control visibility, functionality, and display. If we attempt to do these with buttons already created as you have, it gets nasty and dirty very quickly. So then what do we do? Well, let's create a small class to hold some of our button information.

```
public class MyButton : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Assume all properties did change notifications

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    public Visibility Visibility { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's just assume you have either a `ObservableCollection` of these buttons in either a ViewModel or the Window itself.

You may be thinking, "well, that's great and all, but I am still having to bind all of this to the buttons I have." You would be wrong!

WPF has many containers. One of them being an [`ItemsControl`](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/). With that we can take our collection of `MyButton` and have it do all the leg work for us. Can you taste the cleanliness? Tasty isn't it?

```
<ItemsControl Items="{Binding YourCollectionOfMyButton}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Text}"
                        Command="{Binding Command}"
                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now there's some UI work to do to make it look pretty, but there you go. Now it doesn't matter what buttons you have, you don't need to do any work other than updating that collection.

How you want to deal with managing what buttons go in that collection is up to you, but do know that you are no longer jumping through the hoops to manage hardcoded `X` number of buttons. You can clear the collection, add 1 MyButton and be done with it. Need to add 30? You can!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
  switch (btn.Text)
  {
      case "first":
          btn.Text="second";
          break;
      case "second":
          btn.Text="third";
          break;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use an [enum](https://www.dotnetperls.com/enum) to your advantage.

An example would be:

```
public enum Action
{
    Button1_Action1,
    Button1_Action2
}

// In your form/window

private Action _currentAction = Action.Button1_Action1;

// After you click btn2
_currentAction = Action.Button1_Action2;

// After you click btn1
switch (_currentAction)
{
    case Action.Button1_Action1:
        // Do something
        break;
    case Action.Button1_Action2:
        // Do something else
        break;
}
```

Hope this gives you an idea :)